# Why isn't this assignment a type mismatch?

Tags: go

Why isn't this a type mismatch?

From: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability

A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") in any of these cases:
...snip...
x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a named type.
...snip...

Is that because the underlying type of N[] is N[] which is not a named type?

What's the rationale behind it?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type N []N

func main() {
    n := make([]N, 1)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", n)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", n[0])
    n[0] = n
    //fmt.Println(n)
}

*Output:*
[]main.N
main.N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking if `n[0] = n` is valid. You've correctly identified the rule from the language spec:

> A value `x` is assignable to a variable of type `T` ("`x` is
>   assignable to `T`") in any of these cases:
>
> - ...
> - `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical underlying types and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a named type.

And here's how it applies here:

- `n[0]` has type `N` and underlying type `[]N` (from the language specification: "the type to which `N` refers in its type declaration").
- `n` has type `[]N` (with the same underlying type).

So `n[0]` and `n` have identical underlying types (`[]N`), and the type of `n` is not a named type.

Comment: Do you know what the rationale is behind that rule? Besides confusing me of course.

If I change 
    n := make([]N, 1)
to
    n := make(N, 1)
why does that still work? I thought make needed a slice, map or channel.

This is a bit off topic but also why does the following not give an out of bounds error.
    make([]int, 3)[3:]

Comment: @VM7 I think it's an omission in the language spec that it doesn't say what `make(N, 1)` does.